# Convert CSV file to Json using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am facing issue while converting .CSV file to .json file using pyspark.

**MyCode**

```
   from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
   spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

   df_pubs = spark.read.options(inferSchema='True',delimiter=',').csv("filename.csv")
  #df_pubs_json = df_pubs.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).json("filename.json")
  #df_pubs_json = df_pubs.toJSON("filename.json")\
  df_pubs.write.format("json").mode("overwrite").save("filename.json")
```

**Error**

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o31.save.
```

: ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515:

Comment: Does the csv file contain a header?

Comment: No header in csv file.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: What have you tried so far, with a code example? / What do you expect? / What error do you get? For help, take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = spark.read.options(header=True,inferSchema=True,delimiter=",").csv("filename.tsv")
df1 = df.toJSON()
df_final = spark.read.json(df1)
df_final.toPandas().to_json("filename.json",orient='records')
```